# Lowering superscript to match elements without tilde

Tags: superscripts, tilde

Consider:

```
\[
\mathrm{A}^{+}\tilde{\mathrm{A}}^{+}
\]
\[
\mathrm{Aa}^{+}\tilde{\mathrm{Aa}}^{+}
\]
```

[image]

Is there a simple way to lower the final plus-sign, so that it aligns with the first three?

(This is a follow-up to my previous question, but I suspect that the solution will be very different...)

Comment: `\tilde{\mathrm{Aa}}\vphantom{A}^{+}` seems to work.

Comment: On my screen it's off by the tiniest margin, but it's good enough for me! Should I remove this question or keep it up?